# Memory management & viewDidUnload?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have a viewController setup as below:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}
```

when it comes to memory management should I be adding release to both viewDidUnload & dealloc?

```
-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [locationManager release];
    locationManager = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


-(void)dealloc {
    [locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

cheers Gary

EDIT:

[super dealloc] moved to bottom as per Deans kind comment.

Comment: Just noticed - you should put [super dealloc] as the _last_ line in your dealloc method. Otherwise you might get a crash when you try to release locationManager because the memory might already be being used fr another object. (Very unlikely but something to watch out for)

Comment: Thank you Dean, my mistake but a good one to keep in mind, thanks again.

Comment: @dean: How can locationManager's memory be used for another object if you hadn't released it yet? (referring to the original code posted)

Comment: It can't, locationManager is fine. However, when you call [super dealloc] it will release the memory for the MapViewController i.e. it will free _self_. Then, when you try to call release on locationManager, you have no idea what locationManager is now pointing to because some oter thread might have grabbed the memory _self_ used to be in. You might crash and you might leak locationManager or you might release some other object you've never heard of!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer :**

Unless you are creating/retaining it in viewDidLoad (or a xib), don't release it in viewDidUnload.

**Long answer :**

viewDidUnload is used to release anything that you might have made when the view is created - this included things in viewDidLoad but also includes and IBOutlet properties that are created from inside a xib file. these should all be released and set to nil in viewDidUnload.

Anything else should just be released in dealloc.

The idea is that if viewDidUnload is called to free some memory, the view can be recreated again completely from your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Can I clarify your answer, I am instantiating locationManager in viewDidload, so its right to release it in viewDidUnload (if the view gets unloaded) and also right to release it in dealloc for situations where the app exits with the view still loaded?

Comment: If you're instantiating it in viewDidLoad then yes, release it in viewDidUnload (assuming that you don't want location updates until the view is loaded again!). And you're right again - release it in dealloc :)

Answer (score 5):

In `viewDidUnload` you should be setting your IBOutlet properties to nil and anything that is initialized in `viewDidLoad`.

Remember that if the phone is low on memory, your view will be unloaded if it isn't on-screen. Next time your view is loaded again, new views will be connected to the IBOutlets and viewDidLoad will be called again. So you should set the outlet properties to nil in `viewDidUnload` to reduce the memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

The guy is doing a [object release] before doing the self.object = nil;

Is the first release for nothing ? In the Apple documentation, they simply affect nil to the variable... what is right?

Comment: If your instance variables are declared as @property(retain) then you can simply use [self setMyVariable: nil]; this will then release the old object and retain nil. In my example above I was not using @property, hence the manual release and nil.

Comment: locationManager = nil won't cause it to be released, as it operates directly on the ivar. So you either need to explicitly release it, or use the mutator ([self setLocationManager:nil] or self.locationManager = nil) to cause the previously retained value to be released. I personally prefer the version in his example ([locationManager release], locationManager = nil), as it more explicitly states what's going on.